# How to mount proper /boot directory using u-boot and x86

Tags: embedded-linux, bootloader, u-boot

My boot chain is EFI --> U-Boot (as EFI app) --> loading itb file to the ramdisk --> starting kernel. When system ends startup process, and I've checked the /boot directory, I expected to see boot.cfg and image.itb files. I see bzImage file instead. Device architecture is x86_64.

My image content looks like:

```
|system.img:
|--EFI\
|----BOOT\
|------bootx64.efi
|------uboot.env
|--boot.cfg
|--image.itb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was kernel had no drivers to SATA AHCI. The solution was to add a driver to configuration and rebuild kernel.